# mat-select multiple how to get ID of individual checkbox checked

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a multiple `mat-select` of locations. On `selectionChange` (selecting or deselecting any location), $event.value is returning an array of all selected location ids. How can I get the id of just the specific location that is being changed?

Example, I have 3 locations in the dropdown. When I check the box for location with id=1, all I want to return is 1, not an array of every location id selected including 1.

```
<mat-form-field class="w-100">
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="locationNameSelectedItems" formControlName="locationName" [compareWith]="compareFn" multiple
    (selectionChange)="OnAgencyLocationSelect($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let location of locationNameDropdownList" [value]="location.id">{{location.itemName}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to move event handling into the `mat-option` instead of the `mat-select`, pass the current element to the event handling function and adapt the function in the Component code accordingly.

Template code:

```
<mat-form-field class="w-100">
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="locationNameSelectedItems" formControlName="locationName" [compareWith]="compareFn" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let location of locationNameDropdownList" [value]="location.id"  (onSelectionChange)="OnAgencyLocationSelect($event, location)">{{location.itemName}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

See also modified example from material documentation that demonstrates the case: https://stackblitz.com/edit/xszh5x?file=src%2Fexample%2Fselect-multiple-example.html

Comment: always you use [(ngModel)] and formControlName in the same tag, you're entering in problems